# Comparing Two Pojo List for changes

Tags: java, list, arraylist, pojo

I have two Pojo Classes
`DriverPrimary`, `DriverSecondary`

I am comparing Driver Primary with driver secondary and if there are any changes I need to find that out

Can you please let me know how it is done?

DriverPrimary.java

```
public class DriverPrimary implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String DriverId;
    private String role;

    
}
```

DriverSecondary.java

```
public class DriverSecondary{

    private String driverSecondaryDriverType;
    private String driverSecondaryDriverId;

}
```

```
   List<DriverPrimary> driverPrimary = new ArrayList<DriverPrimary>();
   List<DriverSecondary> driverSecondary = new ArrayList<DriverSecondary>();

driverPrimary=DataEBO.getDriverPrimary();// from datasource which is not empty and has values
driverSecondary=DataDTO.getDriverSecondary();// from datasource which is not empty and has values
```

SO how to compare the above two list, though the field names are different both have similar values

Edited:
Removed Equals and hashcode has that will work with class with same structure.
Edit2: modified the code for better understanding

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: More details would be helpful though, e.g., where does the list `driverPrimary` come from, how do the constructors look like.

Comment: @david what are you trying to check here? Because you check whether a given _secondary_ driver is in the list of _primary_ drivers. Yet you say "changed" and the example you give - the two elements are different so should not compare equal.

Comment: DriverPrimary comes from a Database POJO where it is defined as a list where as Driver Secondary is from Webservices. So i have it as a list and able to get the values

Comment: yeah I am new to java, so just understood that equals will work on same class structure

Comment: So does the list named `driverPrimary` contain any values while you make the checks?

Comment: driverPrimary  has DriverId and role whereas driverScondary has driverSecondaryDriverId and driverSecondaryType. just the names are different but values are similary type

Comment: I mean: do you `add` any `DriverPrimary` instance to the `driverPrimary` list? Because if the list is empty, then `contains` should always return `false` as far as I know.

Comment: edited the code to remove equals and hascode . can someone suggest me a better way to check two different list objects to check any changes in values

Comment: @gthanop list is not empty, i am able to get the values

Comment: Usually in Java two different classes are not comparable. If `DriverPrimary.driverId` should be compared to `DriverSecondary.driverSecondaryDriverId` and `DriverPrimary.role` compares to `DriverSecondary.driverSecondaryDriverType`, this may be implemented with a separate method `int compare(DriverPrimary p, DriverSecondary s)`, but why do you need to have these 2 classes at all?

Comment: Updated the code. Just want to compare two different pojo class list object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the lists should be remapped to the classes of another type, to make the contents of the lists "comparable":

```java
// from datasource which is not empty and has values
List<DriverPrimary> primary = DataEBO.getDriverPrimary();
List<DriverPrimary> secondary = DataDTO.getDriverSecondary() // List<DriverSecondary>
        .stream()
        .map(sec -> new DriverPrimary(
            sec.getDriverSecondaryDriverId(),  // id  -> id
            sec.getDriverSecondaryDriverType() // type -> role
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());  // List<DriverPrimary>
```

Then, assuming that `equals` and `hashCode` are implemented properly in `DriverPrimary`, the difference between the two lists may be found using for example `List::removeAll` (or just `List::equals`).

```java
List<DriverPrimary> diff1 = new ArrayList<>(primary);
diff1.removeAll(secondary); // items in primary missing in secondary

List<DriverPrimary> diff2 = new ArrayList<>(secondary);
diff2.removeAll(primary); // items in secondary missing in primary
```